# Search a range with 3 tables according to dropdown value

Tags: vba, excel

I'm quite new to macros/formulae of excel. I have a sheet (Sheet1) exported which has the approvers list.

- I also have 3 tables ( A, B, C)

In Sheet2 which has like below values:

- Table A: {aaa,bbb,ccc}
- Table B: {xxx,yyy,zzz}
- Table C: {d12,e12,c12}

I need to search Column Q in sheet1 with either one table as per the dropdown menu.

If I select Table A, then I need to have all rows with text aaa OR bbb OR ccc in Column Q. I used the below formula, but I can search only one table at time.

I can't select through dropdown menu.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A[ID],Q51)))>0
```

This returns true or false. I have to keep changing the formulae for each table. Can I do that through drop down menu.

Answer (score 0):

Use `INDIRECT` : place `INDIRECT(Right(myRange, 1) & "[ID]")` in the place of `A[ID]`.

myRange is the address of the cell where the drop-down is placed; i.e. could be `D1` for example, and the formula becomes:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(INDIRECT(Right(D1, 1) & "[ID]"),Q51))) > 0
```

Comment: Thank you for ur quick turn up. Unfortunately, this doesnt work. It returns false for all the rows irrespective of the table i search. :(